# Is there any "unlock all" cheat for Burnout 3: Takedown?

Tags: burnout-3

I have [Burnout 3: Takedown](http://burnout.wikia.com/wiki/Burnout_3:_Takedown) for Playstation 2. I want to play it casually whenever I have another friend with me. I want to put the game and play one or two races together, and stop playing right afterwards. I don't want to grind for unlockables, I don't want to play single-player. All I want is casual quick-play.

Is there any cheat to unlock all cars/tracks/modes in this game? If there is no such thing, what unlockable cheats does it have?

(just as comparison, Guitar Hero games have such "unlock all" cheats, and they are great when friends get together to just have fun, instead of following a lengthy campaign)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://playstation2.cheats.de/cheat_ausgabe.php?id=228417) you have to enter the following in the main menu to unlock everything:

> L1, L1, L1, R1, R1, R1, R1, R1, L2, L2, L2, L2

Comment: I've tried it, but it did not work. Can anyone confirm it works? I've also seen this cheat (and similar ones) at: http://www.cheatmasters.com/cheats/14212/Burnout_3_Takedown_cheats.html